# applying knockout if and options binding together in one data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to move an if statement into a data-bind but i am running into an error stating:

> Multiple bindings (if and options) are trying to control descendant
>   bindings of the same element.

what i am trying to do is to control the visibility of a dropdown list so it doesn't appear based on the if statement condition. I tried to use the visible bind but it only removed the dropdown elements not the actual dropdown.

This is what i am currently attempting:

```
<select id="IdField" name="Id" data-placeholder="Select an item" data-bind="if: items().length > 0, options: items(), optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: DdlSelectedValue, event: { change: selectChanged }">
                </select>
```

This is what my original code looked like:

```
 <!-- ko if: items().length > 0 -->
                <select id="IdField" name="Id" data-placeholder="Select an item" data-bind="options: items(), optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: DdlSelectedValue, event: { change: selectChanged }">
                </select>
            <!--/ko-->
```

is there a way i could move the if statement into the data-bind with the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is the correct way if you want the `select` to actually be absent from the page when `items().length` is zero.

Alternately, you could use `visible`, which is of course slightly different (when `items().length` is 0, the `select` will be there, it'll just be hidden):

```
<select id="IdField" name="Id" data-placeholder="Select an item" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0, options: items(), optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: DdlSelectedValue, event: { change: selectChanged }">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks.. the issue that i get from this is when i tried the visible - i still get an empty dropdown list on the page - it doesn't seem to remove the actual dropdown list but just the items within...?

Comment: @user3244544: As I said: Using `visible`, the `select` will be in the DOM, but not visible on the page: http://jsbin.com/vakun/1 From the user's perspective, it's not there at all.

Comment: yes i am seeing what you are saying... i also just noticed that with `visible: items().length > 0` that the dropdown is showing appropriately initially but when i try to reuse the feature the dropdown doesn't appear again unless i refresh the page.

Comment: @user3244544: Shouldn't do, not if `items` is observable and you use it to add/remove items: http://jsbin.com/vakun/2

Comment: i guess that is my problem.. i am having `items` as a `ko.computed`

Comment: @user3244544: That should be okay, *provided* what it's based on is observable: http://jsbin.com/vakun/3